# python lxml etree parsing an fvdl file

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, xml.etree

The file contains the following  lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FVDL xmlns="xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/fvdl" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.9" xsi:type="FVDL">`
<CreatedTS date="2013-08-06" time="11:8:48" />`
```

I am trying to read the version tag in FVDL.I am using lxml etree and my code snippet is

```
from lxml import etree
with open(os.path.join(analysis,"merged-results.fvdl") ,"r") as file_handle:
  context = etree.parse(file_handle)
  ver = context.xpath('//FVDL')
  print ver
```

This had worked before in parsing a standard xml file. However it is failing for the above mentioned file .(ver is an empty list at the end of execution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to @falsetru's answer

(By *"trying to read the version tag"*, I understand "the version attribute" (which may not be what you want))

Explicitly register fvdl namespace, under the "fvdl" prefix:

```
ver = context.xpath('//fvdl:FVDL/@version',
          namespaces={"fvdl": "xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/fvdl"})
```

**Or, riskier**, if somehow you know you want the `version` attribute from the root node

```
ver = context.xpath('/*/@version')
```

Both give `['1.9']`

Comment: If you don't know the anonymous namespace (it's the None entry in context.nsmap), you can do something like: `namespaces = dict((k or 'fvdl', v) for k, v in context.nsmap.iteritems())`

Answer (score 1):

```
context = etree.parse(file_handle)
ver = context.getroot()
print ver.attrib['version']

output:'1.9'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[local-name()=...]`:

```
ver = context.xpath('//*[local-name()="FVDL"]')
```